# Update setState in condition using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am new to React Hooks. I have been learning this language with a number of questions in stackoverflow. Even though I have explored the other questions here for 3 days to figure out my following issue, I have not found a proper way.

The following link is my simplified code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [render, setRender] = useState(true);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setRender(!render)}>Render</button>
      {show ? (
        <div>
          <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
          <button onClick={() => setShow(!show)}>Hide</button>
        </div>
      ) : /// setShow(true) <- How can I update it?

      null}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

From my example, what I want to try is, when **Hide** button is clicked, **Hello CodeSandbox** disappears because it is `null` after show becomes `false`. However, the issue is when I click **Render** button, it should display **Hello CodeSandbox** again but it doesn't. I believe the reason is because **show** state still remains `false`. Thus, I want to update **show** state to `true` once **Render** button is clicked so that **Hello CodeSandbox** appears.

Is it possible if I can update state before using `null`? Or is there any better way?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question itself. Avoid relying only on off-site resources for your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are rendering based on the state `show`, so your `Render` button should manipulate that state, just set it back to `true` when it is clicked:

```
function App() {

 const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setShow(true)}>Render</button>
      {show ? (
        <div>
          <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
          <button onClick={() => setShow(false)}>Hide</button>
        </div>
      ) :
      null
     }
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit React Hooks Counter Demo (forked)]

Answer (score 1):

Just create a function that will update both states and call it using your render button:

```
function App() {
  const [render, setRender] = useState(true);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);

  const update = () => {
    setRender(!render);
    setShow(!show)
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={update}>Render</button>
      {show ? (
        <div>
          <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
          <button onClick={() => setShow(!show)}>Hide</button>
        </div>
      ) : /// setShow(true) <- How can I update it?

      null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit React Hooks Counter Demo (forked)]

Comment: You should paste your code here as well (in case the link dies in the future).